# Disable Horizontal UICollectionViewCell Pan Gesture On Vertical UICollectionView Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a vertically scrollable `UICollectionView` with cells that have an added horizontal pan gesture.

Is there an advised way to disable the horizontal pan gesture while scrolling the `UICollectionView`? I ask because whenever I do scroll vertically, the slightest movements left or right also trigger the pan gesture and move the cell right or left.

I tried enabling/disabling the `UICollectionView` when the state of the gesture changed but it was difficult to scroll since a pan gesture would be read in almost every touch instance. I also tried doing something I found online in assessing the x/y velocity and determining whether to fulfill the pan gesture. This seemed to prevent any horizontal panning though..

And finally, I need to use pan versus swipe because I need to include conditional statements on a translation threshold when someone pans (i.e. didn't go x distance, return cell back to original position). If there is a way with swipe, I'm all ears!

Relevant code below:

```
func onPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //Attempt 1
    theCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

    let cellView = sender.view!
    let point = sender.translation(in: cellView)
    cellView.center = CGPoint(x: parentView.center.x + point.x, y: cellView.center.y)

    if sender.state == .ended {
        //Attempt 1
        homeCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            cellView.center = CGPoint(x: self.parentView.center.x, y: cellView.center.y)
        })
    }
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

//Attempt 2
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return abs((pan.velocity(in: pan.view)).x) > abs((pan.velocity(in: pan.view)).y)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` to return `false` when the two gesture recognizers are the pan you are creating and the collection view's default scroll recognizer?

Comment: i tried false and it gives me the same type of interaction as the "attempt 1" in my posted code where most gestures read as a pan so scrolling is hardly enabled.

Comment: what I've done in this situation before is tracked the location of the pan gesture in the x position and y position and constrained things when the gesture.state == .changed depending on the new x-y position. There might be a better way but this worked for some specialized circumstances. So in this case if you detect the pan is primarily vertical you would constrain the horizontal from moving until the pan ended.